# Faster way/better idea to display QR code?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, zxing, qr-code

At the moment I'm using this to generate and display my QR code in my android app:

```
    try {
        BitMatrix bm = qrwriter.encode(b.toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                QRCODE_WIDTH, QRCODE_HEIGHT);
        final Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(),
                bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        for (int i = 0; i < QRCODE_HEIGHT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < QRCODE_WIDTH; j++) {
                mBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK
                        : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imgqrcode.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            }
        });
    } catch (WriterException e) {

    }
```

It works fine, but it's very slow to use that nested loop. I have to set `QRCODE_WIDTH` and `QRCODE_HEIGHT` to very small values (which generates very blurry images on high dpi devices) just to get it to generate in a reasonable amount of time. Ideally I'd like to get the device's resolution and base the size of the QR code on that so it always looks clear.

Am I taking the wrong approach with this? Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure from profiling that this is the slow part? You can try creating an array of pixels then setting them all at once but this takes more memory.

You should make the QR code small and let the UI scale it up. Dont render at full size. If it looks blurry then you need to disable anti aliasing.

Comment: A-ha! Thanks, I'm using the `createScaledBitmap` method (learned from [here](http://www.41post.com/4241/programming/android-disabling-anti-aliasing-for-pixel-art)) now and that works perfectly.